# SQL redondeo automático

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cuando realizo el `INSERT` en mi campo `numeric(18,2)` con un valor con decimal, el SQL automáticamente me lo guarda redondeado, Ejemplo:

**Entrada:**

> 11.56

**Valor guardado**

> 12.00

¿Existe alguna función o manera que el SQL no me realice el redondeo?

Comment: En el INSERT no estás usando la función ROUND, porque eso puede afectar

Comment: ¿El valor de "entrada", es directo o a través de un cálculo? Porque el "redondeo automático" no debería hacerse con un campo numeric(18,2). Justamente porque ese campo permite 18 numeros, con 2 decimales. Si pusieras el código del insert o de dónde vienen el valor de "entrada", seguro te ayudamos a corregirlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna a `float`, eso debería ser suficiente para que no te redondee el valor guardado.

```
ALTER TABLE miTabla
ALTER COLUMN column_name float
```

Después sí quieres utilizar `numeric`, deberías tener en cuenta los valores de precisión. Agrego un [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187746.aspx) que te puede ayudar

```
Precisión   Bytes de almacenamiento
1 - 9                 5
10-19                 9
20-28                13
29-38                17
```